# Does IntelliJ IDEA skip maven build lifecycle?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

In my `pom.xml`, I have a plugin copying files from one folder to another.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>install</phase> <!--Other phases don't work in IntelliJ IDEA either-->
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/ui/build</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn clean install`, the files are copied successfully. But you know, I seldom use maven to build and deploy the app, I always click the button in IntelliJ IDEA to deploy the app. In this way, the files are not copied.

[image]

So does the deployment process in IntelliJ IDEA skip maven install? How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: What and why are you doing the copying manually that way? What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to Edit the Run configuration that you are using as in the image shared by you and add Maven Goal to the build step. Try this

- Edit Configurations..
- Before launch `->` Add `->` Run Maven Goal `->` `mvn clean install` (Command Line) `->` OK
- You can reorder Make, Run Maven Goal according to your preference.

Attaching a sample image that can help you add the before launch task -

[image]

So next time when you press the Start button here the maven goal is automatically executed.

PS : `->` relates to (Select/Input)

Comment: hmm, this is symptom treatment! you want to be able to run from IntelliJ and  for that you need to put your resources in the right location!

Answer (score 1):

When your run configuration is like the screenshot indicates, intellij just compiles the module (with the module output paths), and then it runs the target main with the module classpath selected.

If you want to run any maven goals before hand, you need to set those on the Run Configuration in the "Before Launch" where make is.

It looks like you are having problems with resources. These should be automatically copied by IntelliJ into the classpath. This is configured in Setting => Compiler => Resource Pattern.

Comment: One thing that strikes me as odd is that you are copying from /src/main/ui/build, this is the wrong location for resources, you should only have code in main, resources should be in /src/resources/ui/build, then IntelliJ copy them automatically.